# How to calculate the unscaled and unrotated center of an object in absolute coordinates w.r.t top left corner of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

The origin i.e. (0,0) for the below code is the top left corner of the canvas. A rectangle is drawn that has been rotated by 45 degrees clockwise w.r.t the top-left corner(150,150) and it has been scaled by a factor of 2. From this state of the object, I want to calculate the unscaled and unrotated center of the object w.r.t the top-left corner of the canvas. In this particular case,

- The current center, including rotate and scale, w.r.t top-left is (150,295)
- Undoing the rotate brings the center to (250,250)
- Undoing the scale too brings it to (200,200) which is the final value that I'm looking for

One way that I can try do this is to rotate and unscale manually

- Get the center point, get the top-left point, use the `fabric.util.rotatePoint` to rotate the center back by -45 degrees. This gives the unrotated center point.
- Then get the scaled width(`object.getScaledWidth()`) and unscaled width(`object.width`) and then reduce half the difference from the unrotated center point to get the unscaled center point.

I wanted to know if there was any easier way to do this using a transform matrix. In the code below, I'm trying to get the inverse of the current transform matrix of the rectangle object as mentioned [here](http://fabricjs.com/using-transformations) in the docs and then trying to apply the inverse matrix to the center point. This gives me the center point as 0,0 which is because `transformPoint` gives the point in a coordinate space where 0,0 is the center of the object. Any way to get the center w.r.t to the top-left of the canvas using this approach?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas"); 
  var mainBox = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: "#555",
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    hasControls: true,
    hasBorders: true,
    selectable: true,
    left: 150,
    top: 150,
    angle: 45,
    scaleX: 2,
    scaleY: 2
  });
  canvas.add(mainBox);
  canvas.renderAll();
  const { x: parentCx, y: parentCy } = mainBox.getCenterPoint();
  const invertTransform = fabric.util.invertTransform(mainBox.calcTransformMatrix());
  const initCenterPoint = fabric.util.transformPoint(mainBox.getCenterPoint(), invertTransform);
  console.log("Initial center point", initCenterPoint.x, initCenterPoint.y);
});
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas height="500" width="500" id="canvas"></canvas>
<button>Rotate</button>
```